# addChild()/Implicit Coercion - Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm sort of new to Flash. I understand it's nearly obsolete, but the project I'm working on is written in Flash.

My current task is to obtain RGB data from any pixel in a .jpg file. I have done the following so far:

I have saved the image as a .fla file, and converted the image itself into its own custom class, called "StageWheel", with BitmapData as its base class. However, when I do this:

```
  var sWheel:StageWheel = new StageWheel();
  addChild(sWheel);
  sWheel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getColorSample);

  var bitmapWheel:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sWheel.width, sWheel.height);
```

I get an error:

> "Implicit coercion of a value of type StageWheel to an unrelated type flash.display.DisplayObject"

on the line with

```
addChild(sWheel);
```

What does this error mean? Can I not use addChild to add things to the stage this way?

**EDIT**

That worked @LDMS, thank you. I am now trying to do this later on:

```
var rgb:uint = bitMapWheel.getPixel(sWheel.mouseX,sWheel.mouseY);
```

and get an error

> "1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getPixel through a reference with static type flash.display:Bitmap."

What does this mean? Can I not use getPixel on a Bitmap? Sorry for the newbiness, for some reason Flash is extremely difficult for me to learn.

Comment: Sorry. I created a .fla file with the .jpg image inserted on the stage, then converted the .jpg file to a bitmap, and created the custom class.

Comment: Yes, true. Still getting the same error after trying what you said. If the base class is BitmapData, why would I define bitmapWheel as a Bitmap?

Comment: As you have it, with your `bitmapWheel` var, you are just creating a new empty BitmapData that matches the width and height or your sWheel bitmap data.  your `sWheel` instance is already BitmapData, you don't need to create another bitmap data var.

Comment: You have some inconsistencies with how your spell `bitmapWheel` (eg. uppercase M sometimes).

Comment: Thank you for all of the help! Solved.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, first time posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StageWheel` class is BitmapData, which is not itself a display object that can be added to the stage.

You need to wrap your bitmap data into a `Bitmap` to make it a display object.

```
var sWheel:BitmapData = new StageWheel(); //This is bitmap data, which is not a display object, just data at this point.

//to display the bitmap data, you need to create a bitmap and tell that bitmap to use the bitmap data
var bitmapWheel:Bitmap = new Bitmap(sWheel);

//now you can add the bitmap to the display list
addChild(bitmapWheel);
```

**EDIT**
For the second part of your question, you need to acess the bitmap data of the bitmap to use `getPixel`

```
bitmapWheel.bitmapData.getPixel(bitmapWheel.mouseX,bitmapWheel.mouseY);
```